# How do I create translation without default language content?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

In Drupal 8, my default language is English, but I also have German. How can I create a content item that will only be available for German, and not in English? In other words, how do I created "translated only" content?

When I add new content, I can use the Language select box, but it still creates content available in the English language.

Comment: That's a good question! Can you maybe add some information about how you plan the language switch should work? Will it always only lead to the front page of your site? Or do you plan to have no language switch at all?

Comment: There will be a language switch, but it'll only go to the front page of the site.

Comment: OK Let's dig a little bit deeper. What's the exact problem? That the German content appears in the English menu? Maybe you simply should build two entirely different menus. One for each language. You'll have a custom language switcher right? So the English version of the German content can never get accessed at all. Maybe you first build that custom switcher, do you have it already working?

Comment: @leymannx - good idea about a different menu for each language. There won't be an English version if I can figure out how to do this

Answer (score 1):

It used to take several contributed modules to make even a small multi-lingual Drupal 7 site. Now, you can translate everything using just the Drupal 8 core.

**Step 1: Enable the translation modules**

You need to enable these four core Drupal modules in order to translate your site.
[image]

**Step 2: Translate the Drupal core**

First, let's translate of the core language inside the Drupal. In this example, I'm going to add Spanish as an option on my site:

- Go to Configuration > Languages
- Click "Add language"
- Choose your language and click "Add language".
  [image]
  Click on the percentage area, under "Interface Translation".
  [image]
  You'll be able to search for and manually translate all the language strings in here:
  [image]
  **Step 3: Translate your own site set-up**
- Go to Structure > Content types, you'll see a "Translate" option for your content types:
  [image]
- Inside the next screen, you'll see similar "Translate" links for all your fields:
  [image]

**Step 4: Add content**

Now we can add content to your Drupal site.

- Go to Configuration > Content language and translation.
- Click the box next to "Content":

[image]

**Note:** This is an important step as you can set a specific translation for your content type. That means, the content type default language will be set to a particular language(like German).

[image]

> After this step, all content of "Biography" type will be by default translated to german.

Comment: This really is a nice step-by-step but unfortunately it doesn't answer OP's question as he's asking about language-exclusiveness.

Answer (score 0):

In your node type multilingual settings, you can switch to fixed language. (Sorry for my short answer, I'm using my phone)

Comment: Hmm. In the content type edit page, I see a "Language settings" section, and it lets me change the default language for new content. I see no option for "fixed language".

Comment: Between, which Drupal version are you using ? 7? 8?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 8